# Invariant check at compile time

Tags: c++

Is there some way of checking an invariant of a variable at compile time? For example I have a vector `permutation` which is initialized with values from `0` to `n-1` and then it should only be allowed to perform operations on `permutation` that keep that invariant (basically swapping).

I could write a class `Permutation`, but then I would have implement all possible member functions that are allowed individually (I could not use `std::sort` although it just uses swapping). Is there some way to express such an invariant conveniently?

Comment: Nope. Anything you could come up won't worth the effort, probably.

Comment: Seconded on the No.  Especially if run time becomes involved.  A compile time check wont stop the invariant from being invalidated at run time.

Comment: How can you invalidate it at runtime? Isn't it basically the same as ```const```, only the compile-time check is harder?

Comment: A `const vector<T>` doesn't stop you from modify the values inside the vector.